# Liquibase RollBack against Dockerized Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, docker, liquibase

Having a Dockerized Spring-Boot app and a PostgreSQL database,
how can I issue the cmd

```
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackCount=4 -Dliquibase.password=*********
```

or any equivalent, 
against the database?
Notice that all my changelongs are in the Spring-Boot project's resource folder, and I'm able to run the above CMD from the root of the project.

This is the **dockerfile** of the **Spring-Boot app**:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    JAVA_OPTS=""

CMD java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war

EXPOSE 8080 5701/udp

ADD *.war /app.war
```

and this the PostgreSQL service within a docker-compose:

```
app-postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.6.5
    mem_limit: 256m
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD}
```

I'm able to login to the app container, but there is no changelog file or maven or liquibase installed, since everything is packaged in app.war

**Update**

I was thinking to make a backup of the dockerized DB, restore it locally, then run the rollback command from the project's root.
In the end I'd make a backup of the local DB and restore it on the container.

Probably this is the easiest way. However I hope there exists an alternative way without the need to move and restore the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your migration against WAR file. Search more [here](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) "Run Migrator pulling changelogs from a .WAR file". So if you are able to execute command inside container, you should be able to execute liquibase also.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by following my "strange" idea.

First I did a backup of the dockerized DB,
then I restored it to the local DB.

Locally I was able to run the rollback command, and made the required updates.

In the end I restored it on the dockerized DB.

I hope it could help if someone else runs into the same trouble.